Google pay deeplinking intent payment not working. Its show, it looks like you've reached a UPI limit
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
private fun Google_pay_payment() {
    val Account_Holder_Name = "NAME"
    val My_Random_Refrence_number = getRandomString(14)
    val uri = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "upiid")  //your-merchant-id
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", Account_Holder_Name)  //your-merchant-name
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", My_Random_Refrence_number)  //your-transaction-ref-id
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Paying to $Account_Holder_Name") //your-transaction-note
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "1.0") //your-order-amount
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "")
        .build()
    val encode = Base64.encodeToString(uri.toString().toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
    val finalUri = uri?.buildUpon()
        ?.appendQueryParameter("sign", encode)
        ?.build()

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, finalUri)
    intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME)
    startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE)
}

I tried to implement in app google pay intent payment. But when ever i going for payment its getting failed and shows "It looks like you've reached a UPI limit." but when i go for direct google pay app and do payment using upi id its works.
how can i fixed this issue..?
i passed business UPI id for payment.
